# Unable to use rdesktop

Tags: linux, centos, remote-desktop

I am trying to do rdesktop from centos linux to a windows machine but I am just getting below message

```
$] rdesktop xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port

Autoselected keyboard map en-us
```

And no UI. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: I dunno, but here's my syntax. Adjust to your needs. Note: `-k de` is for a german keyboard layout. `rdesktop -g 1920x1020 -x 0x80 -b -k de -u YOURUSER -d YOURDOMAIN -p YOURPASS -r clipboard:"PRIMARYCLIPBOARD" -r sound:"local" YOUR-REMOTE-MACHINE`

Comment: What version of Windows? Have NLA configured?

Comment: Not directly related, but you might want to look at the [freerdp](http://www.freerdp.com/) fork.  It has better support the new versions of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you check the following:

Is remote desktop port reachable (default is 3389)?

```
telnet <ip_of_win_machine> <rdesktop_port>
```

Are you trying to use remote desktop on Windows 7 Starter, Windows 7 Home Basic, or Windows 7 Home Premium? If so then you may not be able to do it since they do not ship with remote desktop and I am not sure if it can be installed later.

And do check the [Windows Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-Event-Viewer), in case there is something there.

Comment: no i am using rdesktop on linux. You were right though issue was with port.

Comment: Please mark the answer as right if it helped you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was there was a need of port forwarding in my network

After doing that, I used rdesktop and it worked fine. Also I have added some more [rdesktop options](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rdesktop) to it specifically `-f` for full screen and `-g 1440x900 -P -z -x l -r`  to make it's performance better.

> rdesktop -f -g 1440x900 -P -z -x l -r -u windowsuser remoteipaddr:newport